# PHP Laravel - Download returning ZIP file with additional size

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I am using Lumen 5.5.

A user may download a zip file that is stored on S3, the PHP will do the following

1. Download the file from S3 to localhost.
2. Send the downloaded file to user.

My function is

```
public function downloadFile(request $request)
{
    $localpath = S3Manager::download($request->s3Key);
    return response()->download($localpath);
}
```

The files are being downloaded with additional size and I am not able to unzip it on my Mac with the following error:

```
Unable to expand file "filename.zip" into "Downloads"
Error 1: Operation not permitted.
```

That's weird because on the Linux machine (backend) I can unzip it easily. I also checked the Content-Length in the browser, the response returned from the server has the correct length (same as in S3) but the downloaded file size is almost double.

In the frontend I am using js-file-download package

```
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download
```

I'm not sure what is the problem.

Comment: Have you checked permissions? PHP may not have rights to write in your Downloads folder

Comment: Yes, PHP is downloading the file to a temp folder that is public. I tried to unzip the file locally. The returned file content to the browser is just bigger than the one exists on the server.